# Shredded storage for two different file with same content?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, shredded-storage, deduplication

if we upload two file, with different name but with same content/data, in same document library. Will shredded storage concept work on that and keep the content of only one file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different files with the same content would not be 'shredded together', which is what I think you're asking. Instead, they would be two different entries into the database each containing the entirety of their contents. As each file is changed over time, those changes would be a shred *for the document that was changed*, again not 'sharing' any particular shred.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work the way you are thinking. It is not file comparing tool rather improve the I/O and reduce Compute Utilization.

Shredded Storage is both improves I/O and reduces compute utilization when making incremental changes to document or storing documents in SharePoint 2013
Read more [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2012/11/12/introduction-to-shredded-storage-in-sharepoint-2013-rtm-update/)